# How to send email ( in this case external smtp server 'turbo smtp') that doesn't end up in spam on hotmail

Tags: email, smtp

We are involved in the project which is designed to gather UK hotels details that our client needs to create a paper guide with most popular and top rated places in the country.

At the begining of each year we automatically send emails out to hotel owners in order to ask them to update their hotel details.

Unfortunately Client reported that some of hotels never received any of the emails nor that email ended up in spam, especially on hotmail mailbox.

Is there any known approach which could help us to overcome that situation?

One of the solutions we tried was to resign from local SMTP server and purchase external SMTP server on turboSMTP, but without effect.

How would you advise us to you deal with that problem or what have you advised to other companies in the past? Surely there must be a way to resolve that problem completely and we would appreciate your prompt help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Sending an email to multiple recipients within the same company may sometimes have that effect. That company’s email firewall often assumes it’s a spam attack.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of factors that come into this. Thankfully, by going for an external SMTP relay, you can offload most of the issues to them.

What you can do, is make sure your domain and emails are configured to increase their validity. Two really key things for this:

- SPF records
- DKIM signing

**SPF**

SPF is basically a whitelist of IPs that can send email for your domain. SPF records are added to your DNS server. There are plenty of SPF generators online that can help ([like this one](https://www.spfwizard.net/)). Your SMTP provider will also need to be included in your SPF record.

**DKIM**

DKIM digitally signs your email to verify that it's been sent by an authorised sender. Your SMTP provider will have info on how to set that up ([turboSMTP docs](https://serversmtp.com/what-is-dkim/)).

If you want to explore more, I recommend Jeff Atwood's (co-founder of SO) article on how horrible email is: http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/